# Is it possible to include businesses in the HERE Geocoder Autocomplete Search?

Tags: here-api

**Use Case:**
I've got a search box where the intention is to search for addresses, cities and businesses, and up to 5 matching locations will be returned. Then, I'll use the geocoder to get lat/lon coordinates for a selected location based upon `locationId`.

**Desired Outcome:** The geocoder autocomplete API works well for cities/states/addresses/etc., but I'd like for the results to include businesses as well (where a business result would come with a `locationId`). Is this going to be possible with the Here API? Using the Places segment of the API would be an option as well if there's a path forward along that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, Geocoder API helps to find only addresses based on housenumber, street, country ,county, pincode but it does not tell you if the address is of a business category.

You can try Places API and check if it works for your usecase. Read more at developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/quick-start-find-text-string.html.

Below is an example of Hotel category(Business) in Sunny Vale, CA. You can get the id and location details here.

```
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/explore?at=37.370831%2C-122.024636&cat=500-5000-0000&cs=pds&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx
```

Comment: It appears that the places API can find places near a point or within a bounding box- could I search within a country? For example, I may want to search for "Apple Headquarters" to get a business location, or "Sunnyvale, CA" to get a city location- but I'd want these searches to just be within the United States.

Comment: Places API is designed to provide nearby places to an user's current location. However you can filter your search within certain radius of given Position or Bounding Box - https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/location-contexts.html. Filtering based on country name is not possible.You can try using geocoder api to get the lat,long for the country and then trigger places api with that lat,long and some radius.

Comment: Thanks for your help!